# Corpus Linguistics Major

Tags: phonology, corpora, discourse-analysis, corpus-linguistics

I want to use corpus in my MA research, but I have a large problem; how can I analyze the data? Do I use software corpora or corpus such as BNC? I know it is according to my research question, but which is easier. If anyone has suggestion for a new and easy topic in this major, please tell me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your teacher is supposed to teach you this.

Comment: @jlawler At my faculty, there is no one is specialized in Corpus Linguistics and how to use it. It is me who want to enter this field.

Comment: Then perhaps a semester at another university in an exchange program is an option. If not, take a look at the textbooks used in classes at other universities and work through them by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of software packages available for doing corpus analysis. When I was still working in the field, the most commonly used ones were [WordSmith](https://lexically.net/wordsmith/) and [AntConc](https://www.laurenceanthony.net/software/antconc/).

However, you can only do the kind of analyses these packages support, so if you can program, you can write your own software which does exactly what you want to do. This is the approach I followed.

If you are on a Unix system, there are lots of programs available that you can put together as a pipeline, the '[text tools](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-text-manipulation-tools)'. These are enough for doing word frequency lists etc. Using awk, you can also perform more complex tasks.

You would typically get text corpora in a plain text format (sometimes with XML or other markup), so any programs that can read and manipulate text should be useful.